# Javascript not reloading my images when it restarts the carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code, for some reason every time it goes back to the start of the carousel my images takes so long to reload, like very long. Javascript not reloading my images when it restarts the carousel. I must be missing some part in my Javascript. I have tried adding $(document).ready(function()

HTML

```
 <div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://kajabi-storefronts-production.kajabi-cdn.com/kajabi-storefronts-   production/file-uploads/themes/2154565863/settings_images/1376bf3-356e-dbb-540-72f5f6572cc_1.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://kajabi-storefronts-production.kajabi-cdn.com/kajabi-storefronts-production/file-uploads/themes/2154565863/settings_images/850fa1e-828-aaf3-d3f-08f588ecb1d_3.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://kajabi-storefronts-production.kajabi-cdn.com/kajabi-storefronts-production/file-uploads/themes/2154565863/settings_images/b41302b-fa7b-d6f-2655-e8385f7a3c1_2.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  let slideIndex = 0;
  let timeoutId = null;
  const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  const dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  
  showSlides();
  function currentSlide(index) {
       slideIndex = index;
       showSlides();
  }
 function plusSlides(step) {
    
    if(step < 0) {
        slideIndex -= 2;
        
        if(slideIndex < 0) {
          slideIndex = slides.length - 1;
        }
    }
    
    showSlides();
 }
  function showSlides() {
    for(let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
      dots[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if(slideIndex > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.add('active');
     if(timeoutId) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
     }
    timeoutId = setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
  }
```

Tried adding this but its still not working

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    <<JAVASCRIPT>>
  });
```

Comment: on line 4 of the html I see, there are a few spaces in the URL that I don't think should be there, without those it works fine for me

Comment: I think the problem I had was adding two sliders to the page, which gave an error. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are increasing the slideIndex before checking if it has gone beyond the total number of slides. This is causing the images to not reload properly when the carousel restarts.
Try this:

```
function showSlides() {
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
    dots[i].classList.remove('active');
  }

  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.add('active');

  if (timeoutId) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }

  timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    slideIndex++; // 
    showSlides();
  }, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much. Adding this code makes the carousel not work at all.  I have added my old code back and Here's a link for you to see what it looks like [link](https://www.andshedrawsbig.academy/mini-course-1/#section-1692883992332)

Comment: please see message above

Comment: I think the problem I had was adding two sliders to the page, which gave an error. Its working now.